# Guava CacheBuilder doesn't call removal listener

Tags: java, collections, guava

***I want:*** Be notified when entity is removed due timeout expiration.

***I tried:*** Set removal listener.

***Problem:***  Seems removal listener doesn't work correct. It work only when I put new items into the cache (see code below)

***Question:*** *How to make removal listener work without putting new items?*

***Code:***

*My loading cache:*

```
LoadingCache<String, Integer> ints = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .maximumSize(10000)
            .expireAfterAccess(ACCESS_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .removalListener(
                    new RemovalListener() {
                        //PROBLEM: THIS METHOD IS NEVER CALLED!!!
                        public void onRemoval(RemovalNotification notification) {
                            if (notification.getCause() == RemovalCause.EXPIRED) {
                                System.out.println("Value " + notification.getValue() + " has been expired");
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Just removed for some reason");
                            }
                        }
                    }
            )
            .build(
                    new CacheLoader<String, Integer>() {
                        public Integer load(String key) throws Exception {
                            return new Integer(-1);
                        }
                    });
```

*how I use cache in separate thread:*

```
cache.put("key", 100);
Thread.sleep(ACCESS_TIMEOUT / 2);
System.out.println(cache.getIfPresent(key)); //returns 100
Thread.sleep(ACCESS_TIMEOUT * 5);
//CRUCIAL STRING: cache.put("key2", 200); //invoke removal listener
System.out.println(cache.getIfPresent(key)); //return null
//And again: the problem is that entity has been already expired, but removal listener isn't called untill I add new item to the cache.
```

***P.S:*** I can share the complete demo at GitHub if you need, just tell me

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's because Guava does not ensure the eviction of the values automatically when the timeout value expires. It however does that during a series of read and write operations.

Per its documentation [here](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained):

> Caches built with CacheBuilder do not perform cleanup and evict values
>   "automatically," or instantly after a value expires, or anything of
>   the sort. Instead, it performs small amounts of maintenance during
>   write operations, or during occasional read operations if writes are
>   rare.
>
> The reason for this is as follows: if we wanted to perform Cache
>   maintenance continuously, we would need to create a thread, and its
>   operations would be competing with user operations for shared locks.
>   Additionally, some environments restrict the creation of threads,
>   which would make CacheBuilder unusable in that environment.

To validate your `onRemoval` on expiration, call [`cache#cleanUp`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#cleanUp%28%29) right before your 2nd read operation and it is supposed to call your `onRemoval`.

Comment: can I reset expiration timeout from removal listener and restore entity? If yes, how?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990133/guava-cachebuilder-imply-additional-conditions-to-entity-removal please