# Guava CacheBuilder: imply additional conditions to entity removal

Tags: java, collections, guava

***I want:*** Remove entity when both conditions are true

- timeout expired
- some external conditions are true

***Question:*** *How should I imply additional removal conditions besides timeout? Or how can I restore entity from removal listener (see code below)?*

***My code (which already remove based on timeout only):***

```
LoadingCache<String, Integer> ints = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .maximumSize(10000)
        .expireAfterAccess(ACCESS_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .removalListener(
                new RemovalListener() {                       
                    public void onRemoval(RemovalNotification notification) {
                        if (notification.getCause() == RemovalCause.EXPIRED) {
                            if (!isExternalCondition()) {
                               //IS IT POSSIBLE TO RESTORE?
                              restore(notification.getValue()); 
                            }
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Just removed for some reason");
                        }
                    }
                }
        )
        .build(
                new CacheLoader<String, Integer>() {
                    public Integer load(String key) throws Exception {
                        return new Integer(-1);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if you could do this.

Answer (score -1):

Try Static class with **isExternalCondition**() method.